# Multiple declarations of 'MyModule.myTypeclassFunction'

Tags: haskell

in Main.hs

```
class A aable where
    getName :: aable → String

class B bable where
    getName :: bable → String
```

returns this compilation error with Leksah/ghc

```
src\Main.hs:23:4:
    Multiple declarations of `Main.getName'
    Declared at: src\Main.hs:20:4
                 src\Main.hs:23:4
```

I need both to be able to return a name, with a different signification in both cases.
Should I declare class A and B in two different modules ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kneejerk reaction: Use `Show`. Reading better, I see that what you want is propably different semantically (despite identical type signatures). Why not use a different name? `descriptionA` and `descriptionB` perhaps? Declaring them in different modules would solve the compilation error, but (1) you still have two different things with the same name and (2) whenever you import both modules (unqualified), you'll get the same error.

Comment: @ok, so you mean, I should use different names or use Show when it is about String. What about using newType so as to qualify the strings so as they are incompatible, if they mean totally different things ? Is it common to use newType ?

Comment: @stephane Imagine a type, `T` (any type, it could be a newtype) and now imagine you have `instance A T where ...` and an `instance B T where ...`  How do you know which function to run when someone calls `getName`?

Comment: @Stephane: As always, it depends. If the strings represent conceptually different things, I'd propably choose this way (if only to make the type signature more expressive: `xyz :: thing -> ThingID` instead of `xyz :: thing -> String`)

Comment: @delnan... yep this last suggestion is pretty good. In my exercise - not developed here - I was awkwardly trying to model the coordinates of a categorial denotator in its coordinator (a string name space), so ThingID is obviously what I was missing to express. thx.

Answer (score 3):

When you have different data types that behave differently, but somewhat the same (as in, have the same methods but differing implementations), then it's Haskell classes to the rescue!

```
data A = A { nameA :: String } deriving (Show, Eq)
data B = B { nameB :: String } deriving (Show, Eq)

class Named a where
    getName :: a -> String

instance Named A where
    getName = nameA

instance Named B where
    getName = nameB
```

---

```
ghci> getName $ A "foo"
"foo"
ghci> getName $ B "bar"
"bar"
```

(If you haven't seen record syntax yet, there's a [good explanation at LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax))

You can even be more general than that.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}
-- The above line should be at the top of your file

-- add this to the file too (anywhere)
instance (Show a) => Named a where
    getName = show
```

---

```
ghci> getName 3
"3"
ghci> show 3
"3"
ghci> getName $ A "foo"
"foo"
ghci> show $ A "foo"
"A {nameA = \"foo\"}"
```

The OverlappingInstances language pragma is only necessary in this example if you keep both the `Instance (Show a) => Named a` and the `instance Named A`, since I made `A` an instance of `Show` by deriving it. Use language pragmas with caution and wisdom.

I made `A` and `B` data for illustrative purposes, but the `(Show a)` instance illustrates how this could also be done just as easily for classes.

Comment: Can you make the following work too: `x = A "Foo"; y = B "Bar"; z = x {name="Bar"}; w = y {name="Foo"}`?